# Animation Not Functioning Correctly and Animation Unrepeatable

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, repeat

My practice website has a couple new problems. The first is that one of the animated page transitions is not animating. Upon clicking the Home button located above the History Page object, the History Page simply snaps back to its original location offscreen, rather than sliding back like it should. I can't figure out what's causing this. The animation functioning incorrectly is ".animate2"/"SlideOut".

The other problem is that, once an animation has been run it seems that it cannot be triggered again. Does anyone know of a good way to fix this (preferably without JQuery)?

Here's the Homepage HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="Wrapper">
    <div id="Home">

        <div class="Box">
            <div id="PledisHover">
                <img class="Pledis" src="Pledis.png">
                    <img class="PledisHov" src="PledisHov.png">
        </div>

        <img class="SVT" src="SayTheName.png">

        <img class="Logo" src="Logo.png">

            <div id="HistHover" onClick="">
                <img src="HistButton.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='HistButtonHover5.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='HistButton.png'">
            </div>

            <div id="MembHover" onClick="">
                <img src="MemButton.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='MemButtonHov.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='MemButton.png'">
            </div>

            <div id="MedHover" onClick="">
                <img src="MedButton.png" 
onmouseover="this.src='MedButtonHov.png'"
onmouseout="this.src='MedButton.png'">
            </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Hist">
        <img id="HomeButton" src="Home.png" onmouseover="this.src='HomeHov.png'" onmouseout="this.src='Home.png'">
        <object id="Page" name="Page" type="text/html/css" data="SVTHist.html">
        </object>
    </div>

    <div id="Memb">
        <object id="Page" name="Page" type="text/html/css" data="SVTMemb.html"></object>
    </div>

    <div id="Med">
        <object id="Page" name="Page" type="text/html/css" data="SVTMed.html"></object>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Homepage CSS:

```
html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    #Wrapper {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        overflow: hidden;
         }

    #Hist, #Memb, #Med {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 1364px;
        }

    #Home {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background: linear-gradient(#F293BF 50%, #EBEFF8 50%);
        }

    .Box {
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attatchment: fixed;
        background: linear-gradient(#94DBF7, #D2EAF7);
        height: 646px;
        width: 1202px;
        position: relative;
        left: 5.5%;
        top: 25px;
        }

        .Pledis, .PledisHov, .SVT, .Logo, #HistHover, #MembHover, #MedHover {
            position: absolute;
                    }

        #HistHover, #MembHover {
            top: 543px;
                   }

        #HistHover:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
                }

        .Pledis {
            top: 15%;
            left: 15%;
            }

            .PledisHov {
                top: 78px;
                left: 175px;
                transform: rotate(-15deg);
                   }

    .PledisHov, #PledisHover:hover .Pledis {
        display: none;
                    }

    .Pledis, #PledisHover:hover .PledisHov {
        display: block;
                    }

        .SVT {
            top: 10%;
            left: 20%;
            }

        .Logo {
            top:48%;
            left: 37%;
            }

    #HistHover {
        left: 25%;
           }

    #MembHover {
        left: 42%;
           }

    #MedHover {
        top: 553px;
        left: 59%;
          }

    #Page {
        height: 702px;
        width: 1364px;
        }

        .animate {
            -webkit-animation-name: Slide;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            }

        @-webkit-keyframes Slide {
            from {transform: translateX(0px)}
            to {transform: translateX(-1364px)}
             }

        @keyframes Slide {
            from {transform: translateX(0px)}
            to {transform: translateX(-1364px)}
          }


        .animate2 {
            -webkit-animation-name: SlideOut;
            -webkit-animation-duration: 1.7s;
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
            }

        @-webkit-keyframes SlideOut {
            from {transform: translateX(-1364px)}
            to {transform: translateX(1364px)}
             }

        @keyframes SlideOut {
            from {transform: translateX(-1364px)}
            to {transform: translateX(1364px)}
          }

    #HomeButton {
        position: absolute;
        top: 2px;
        left: 9px;
          }
```

Homepage Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('HistHover').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Hist').classList.remove('animate2');
            document.getElementById('Hist').classList.add('animate');
});

    document.getElementById('HomeButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Hist').classList.remove('animate');
            document.getElementById('Hist').classList.add('animate2');
                                         });

    document.getElementById('MembHover').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Memb').classList.remove('animate2');
            document.getElementById('Memb').classList.add('animate');
                                         });

    document.getElementById('HomeButton2').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Memb').classList.remove('animate');
            document.getElementById('Memb').classList.add('animate2');
                                         });

    document.getElementById('MedHover').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Med').classList.remove('animate2');
        document.getElementById('Med').classList.add('animate');
                                         });

    document.getElementById('HomeButton3').addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.getElementById('Med').classList.remove('animate');
            document.getElementById('Med').classList.add('animate2');
                                         });
```

EDIT: I solved half of my problem- the animations are now repeatable. All I had to do was add a line to each function telling it to remove whichever animation class had finished before the button press. I have updated the javascript section of the code shown here to reflect this change.

Unfortunately, "animation2" is still not playing correctly. The object is still snapping into place, rather than sliding in. I will update this post if I manage to solve it.

EDIT 2: I got the animation working correctly. Turns out, I simply had the objects snapping to the wrong position to start the animation from. I adjusted the starting position and now it works perfectly. I updated the keyframe portions of the CSS shown above to reflect this change.

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle or working code sample we could look at?

Comment: @thewolff [Here](https://codepen.io/PeachyPlnk/project/editor/Xgamzn). The images don't show up, but the relevant buttons are the bottom left on the homepage and the top left on the history page.

Comment: We don't do "SOLVED" in the title here. If you answered your own question you can post it below and accept it, or delete the question. Thanks.